# Displaying Json string in Handlebars using node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Using node.js and handlebars I am trying to display a query using JSON.Stringify() function
javascript:

```
res.render('search', {"data" : JSON.stringify(data)});
```

the handblebars code search.handlebars:

```
<div>
{{data}}
</div>
```

which displays: 
[{"media_name":"Edge of Darkness (2010)"},{"media_name":"Tim (1979)"},{"media_name":"We Were Soldiers (2002)"},{"media_name":"\"The Tonight Show with Jay Leno\" (1992) {(#20.49)} (archive footage)"}, ...]

I am trying to loop through this code using

```
{{#each}}
<li>
{{data.media_name}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

so that i can pull out individual indexes: data[4] and have "Edge of Darkness (2010)" formatting without the {}. But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It might be a handlebars formatting question.

Comment: You won't be able to loop through the data if the data is a string. Remove the `JSON.strigify` call.

Comment: I see that makes since so i just need to format it correctly. Thanks

Comment: I see i was confused by the data being an array in the json "data", Thanks again!